# Convergence of $X_nY_n$ in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

I have a short question: Is always true that if $X_n$ converges to $X$ in distribution and $Y_n$ converges to $Y$ in probability then $X_nY_n$ converges to $XY$ in distribution?

Answer (score 1):

No: let $X=\pm 1$ with probability $1/2$, $X_n:=(-1)^nX$ and $Y_n:=X$ for each $n$. Then $X_n\to X$ in distribution, $Y_n \to X$ in probability but $X_nY_n=(-1)^n$ which does not converge (in any sense).